# Page returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: asp.net, json

When compiled and ran, the page displays valid JSON; however, when the same page is invoked using `WebClient`, the entire HTML code pulls through and therefore the JSON can not be parsed.

```
'ASP Code:
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data"%>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb"%>
        <%Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-type", "application/json")%>
        <%
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection
        Dim objAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim objTable As DataTable
        Dim objRow As DataRow
        Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim outp
        Dim c
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=test\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDb;User ID=sa;Password=test;OLE DB Services=-2;")
            objAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from cars", conn)
        objAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "myTable")
        objTable=objDataSet.Tables("myTable")

        outp = ""
        c = chr(34)
        for each x in objTable.Rows
        if outp <> "" then outp = outp & ","
                outp = outp & "{" & c & "Make" & c & ":" & c & x("make") & c & ","
                outp = outp & c & "Model" & c & ":" & c & x("model") & c & ","
                outp = outp & c & "Year" & c & ":" & c & x("year") & c & "}"
        next

            outp = "{" & c & "records" & c & ":[" & outp & "]}"

            Response.Write(outp)
            conn.Close()
        %>

        //Json Purser:
            private void btnDeserialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                string json = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:82");// Expecting JSon, Found HTML

                Cars c= (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Cars>(json);
                MessageBox.Show(c.Make);
            }
```

Comment: The real answer is that you don't do it that way. ASP.NET aspx files are supposed to be web pages. To just return JSON you would create an ashx web handler, or a web method.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing all the HTML tags from my ASP page and left only the form tag in which the ASP code is wrapped. Worked like magic!